# Issue with HAML indentation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, haml

i am trying to edit a haml file in awestruct project.

When ever i update and run i am gettign following error

```
--------------------
Page: /_layouts/base.html /_layouts/base.html.haml Layout
No changes detected
Dependencies Matrix: (non unique source path)
         Outgoing dependencies:
                 Content -> 0
                 Key     -> 0
         Incoming dependencies:
                 Content <- 12
                 Key     <- 0
--------------------
```

the area i am modifing is

```
          %li
            %a{ :href=>"#{site.base_url}/" } Home
          %li
            %a{ :href=>"#{site.base_url}/news/" } Blog
```

i just wanted to add another li and a element...

Comment: did you use tab for indentening?

Comment: i tried both tab and space...

Comment: tabs dont work with yaml files always use spaces

Comment: i am working on haml with space. still issues comes

Answer (score 0):

It basically says that the content has not modified, and I can't see any errors here.
Just save the changes, restart Awestruct and try again.